# Recursively grep unique pattern in different files

Tags: linux, unix, grep, find

Sorry title is not very clear.
So let's say I'm grepping recursively for urls like this:

`grep -ERo '(http|https)://[^/"]+' /folder`

and in folder there are several files containing the same url. My goal is to output only once this url. I tried to pipe the grep to | uniq or sort -u but that doesn't help

example result:

```
/www/tmpl/button.tpl.php:http://www.w3.org
/www/tmpl/header.tpl.php:http://www.w3.org
/www/tmpl/main.tpl.php:http://www.w3.org
/www/tmpl/master.tpl.php:http://www.w3.org
/www/tmpl/progress.tpl.php:http://www.w3.org
```

Comment: What does `grep` output? Can you show some examples?

Comment: You need to get rid of the portions before ":", they are not unique, then you'll have just your URLs. Try piping to `awk` and then to `uniq`. I'll try and do this myself shortly.

Comment: Hm yeah I was just thinking about that too, but what if I need the position?

Comment: So, this will print only the unique URL, but I'm not sure how you can do that  AND still preserve all the data, not in one go at least. `grep -ERo '(http|https)://[^/"]+' /folder | awk -F ":" '{print $2$3}' | uniq`. It's pretty crude, but if the format of `grep`'s output is consistent it should work.

Comment: Your example output contains the same URL multiple times, while all of your question reads like you would like to retrieve only the first occurrence of each URL. Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the structure of the output is always: 
`/some/path/to/file.php:http://www.someurl.org`

you can use the command `cut` :

`cut -d ':' -f 2-` should work. Basically, it cuts each line into fields separated by a delimiter (here ":") and you select the 2nd and following fields (-f 2-)

After that, you can use `uniq` to filter.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the address and never the file where it was found in, there is a grep option `-h` to suppress file output; the list can then be piped to `sort -u` to make sure every address appears only once:

```
$ grep -hERo 'https?://[^/"]+' folder/ | sort -u
http://www.w3.org
```

If you don't want the `https?://` part, you can use Perl regular expressions (`-P` instead of `-E`) with variable length look-behind (`\K`):

```
$ grep -hPRo 'https?://\K[^/"]+' folder/ | sort -u
www.w3.org
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipe to Awk:

```
grep -ERo 'https?://[^/"]+' /folder |
awk -F: '!a[substr($0,length($1))]++'
```

The basic Awk idiom `!a[key]++` is true the first time we see `key`, and forever false after that. Extracting the URL (or a reasonable approximation) into the key requires a bit of additional trickery.

This prints the whole input line if the key is one we have not seen before, i.e. it will print the file name and the URL for the first occurrence of each URL from the `grep` output.

Doing the whole thing in Awk should not be too hard, either.